# Django Filter And-ing of Related vs Original Predicates

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

Given I have these models:

```
class Student(Model):
  pass

class Exam(Model):
  student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
  is_hard = models.BooleanField(...)
  is_completed = models.BooleanField(...)
```

How would I get filtered QuerySet of Students matching these criteria:

1. Students that have a completed exam and a hard exam. (i.e. the student may have one exam that is hard and one that is completed)
2. Students that have a completed exam that is also a hard exam. (the same exam must be both hard and completed).

I believe that the latter is answered with:

```
Student.objects.filter(exam__is_hard=True, exam__is_completed=True)
```

but how do I get the former?

Answer (score 0):

use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
Student.objects.filter(Q(exam__is_hard=True, exam__is_completed=True)|Q(exam__is_hard=True)|Q(exam__is_completed=True))
```

Comment: There are a few typos in there and I'm not really sure what that is doing.